# Why do these 2 queries have the same "GB processed" (and thus cost)?

Tags: google-bigquery

My test data consists of 27,768,767 rows. My schema includes a "message" column of type string.  The length of these strings vary but are generally a couple of hundred characters.  There is also user_id column of type int.  Here are two queries that both return 0 rows (the where clauses match nothing in my data).  To my surprise, however, they both report 4.69 GB processed.

```
SELECT * FROM logtesting.logs WHERE user_id=1;

Query complete (1.7s elapsed, 4.69 GB processed)
```

.

```
SELECT * FROM logtesting.logs WHERE message CONTAINS 'this string never appears';

Query complete (2.1s elapsed, 4.69 GB processed)
```

Since ints are stored in [8 bytes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data), I would have expected that the data processed in the former (user_id) query would be something like 213MB (28 million rows * 8 bytes per user_id).  The latter (message) query is harder to estimate since the strings vary in length, but I would expect it to be several times greater than the former (user_id) query.

Is my understanding of [how BigQuery calculates query costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#samplecosts) wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter what you do, BigQuery will need to scan all the rows in your tables (not necessarily all the columns though), so it's normal that you get this, since your table doesn't change. The where clause only means it won't RETURN the data. It still needs to process it.

The only way to make sure you lower the processing is to not select all your columns. BigQuery is column based, so if you don't need all your attributes, don't return them all (this also means they won't be processed). THIS will help lower your cost :)

Historically, "select *" wasn't supported to make sure people wouldn't find that out the hard way

Comment: Wow that is super weird.  I would expect that which columns I was selecting wouldn't matter since I had no matching rows, but I just tried `select user_id` instead of `select *` and it definitely changed things.  424 MB processed in the former query and 2.17 GB processed in the latter.  Perhaps read-optimization requires that BigQuery pulls all columns it might ever need (both for where clauses and for returned values) all in one shot, so it can't do the optimization I was assuming.

Comment: Since BigQuery shards, this is actually to be expected. Since it can't know in advance what would be needed or not, it just throws all your table in shards, and each shard filters the results. Since your whole table needs to be sent back and forth, then you're charged for the whole thing. That's why changing the Select is important, as this means only the relevant columns are sent